# When did pathetic and pathetisch divert in meaning?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, etymology, german-to-english

It seems clear that the two words have the same origin, yet *pathetic* and *pathetisch* seem to have significantly different meanings (or don't they?).

*Pathetic* is very negative with synonyms like pitiful, miserable, disgraceful, shameful, despicable, dishonorable etc. 
Whereas *pathetisch* is not necessarily negative, as it just means excessively dramatic or emotional. They do however show up as translations of each other, though usually being somewhere a bit further down on the list.

So first of all, what is the common ground that these two seem to have, how different are they in meaning? When and why did the meanings change? Have they once been used synonymously and if so, which meaning came first?

Comment: dict.cc lists them as translation. Luckily, dict.leo and Pons don't. I consider this an error in dict.cc. This translation wasn't thoroughly checked; I really don't think that there's a single sentence where this is an appropriate translation.

Comment: Yes, it also feels wrong to me. But english wiktionary also lists pathetic as one of the translations of [pathetisch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pathetisch)

Comment: I would guess the P. I. Tchaikovsky - Symphony No. 6 "Pathetique", Op. 74, loosely translated as the pathetic symphony, uses the latter meaning of the word. I would say it would be an error to use this word in modern parlance. The tragic symphony would be a better rendition.

Comment: Has anyone on here heard of the pathetic fallacy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The German word still has the original meaning that was borrowed from Greek.

> [pathetisch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/pathetisch)
> Bedeutung: übertrieben oder aufgesetzt gefühlvoll, leidenschaftlich
>
> Herkunft: über spätlateinisch patheticus → la von altgriechisch παθητικός (pathētikós) → grc „erhaben, feierlich“, einer Ableitung zum Substantiv πάθος (pathos) → grc „Pathos“

The English word originally had the same meaning but it changed.

> [pathetic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pathetic): archaic  Relating to the emotions.

The contemporary English meaning of "arousing pity" is [first recorded in 1737](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pathetic).

So, both words share their origin and meant the same thing many, many years ago. The English one lost its original meaning. I can neither answer when it was declared archaic nor can I say why it had changed. I didn't find anything about that.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly, according to the Google Ngram Viewer, the word _pathetisch_ has not been used in the German language before the 1720s, whereas the english _pathetic_ has been used since the beginning of the 16th century. So that means by the time the english _pathetic_ started to change its meaning further away from its greek origin, the german _pathetisch_ had just begun to become a part of the German vocabulary.

Comment: @Jascha Goltermann: I think it could also mean that the english corpus has many many more books inside then the german in this period. E.g. try to search for "Mutter" in English and German corpus of Google Ngram Viewer.

Comment: Part of the Greek family of "pathos" also is also the verb "pathein" which meant as much as "to suffer". This is where the Latin family of "passion" comes from, which is at its core about "suffering". So if you think of "pathetic" as "miserable" you're kind of close to the original core. The German meaning of "pathetisch" leans more toward the Old French reading of the family which was broadened to evoking emotion. A reading that was also present in Greek and Latin and which also ties in with "miserable" as seeing someone suffer evokes emotion.

Comment: Would be interesting if "patetisch" already had the over the top notion in German back in the days of the "Romantik". As for English, there all you had to do was strip away the element of genuine pity and you're there. Etymonline suggests that happened as late as 1937. Before it was "arousing pity" without negative connotation. ... meh... I guess I should make that an answer. MAybe tomorrow I will. I'm too lazy for the formatting and linking and stuff.

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann... check my two comments for more details on the origin and the meaning shifts.

Comment: Thanks @Emanuel for all the information you have added! You should make that an answer, so it will be easier for people to find it.

Comment: @hellcode, why Mutter in particular - won't you end up comparing completely different words (i.e. en:A repressed or obscure utterance vs. de:Mother)?

Comment: I don't claim to know everything about Ancient Greek - only a moron could- but I studied it for years and I had to speak ΚΑΘΑΡΕΥΟΥΣΑ for decades.  I strongly doubt it ever meant "feierlich". Do you have any sources for this claim?

Comment: @Ludi This is taken from Wiktionary, so this is the source ;). I would rather question "erhaben", this is the odd one out.

Comment: @Em1 Yes. I question both strongly. I would normally have said it is wrong, but Ancient Greek is infinite. My suspicion is increased by the fact, that Liddel gives no such meaning.

Comment: @Ludi Duden says "leidend, leidenschaftlich". I could change it if you think that's better.

Comment: @Em1 no, no, that's not what I doubt. I doubt the "erhaben, feierlich".

Comment: @Simon MᶜKenzie: it is just one example. I tried many simple words that should have occurances in the german corpus, but they haven't - but they occur in english corpus between 1600 and 1720 where the german corpus seems to have "gaps".

Answer (score 4):

My knowledge about the history of these words in German and English is limited, but I am a native speaker of both German and modern Greek and studied ancient Greek until a few years ago.

It is certain, that both of these derive from ancient Greek ΠΑΘΗΤΙΚΟΣ.

[Liddell-Scott in the associated lemma](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=paqhtiko/s) claims that the word originally covered the following senses:

A.capable of emotion

B.Sensuous, impassioned,pathetic

C.Grammatically passive
(I omit two very special compounds you can check for yourself).

It is striking, that Liddell groups **pathetic** with **sensuous** making me wonder, how old the modern connotation of **pathetic** as contemptible is.

It is worth noting, that [this dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0057:entry=paqhtiko/s) documents additional uses beside contemptible, that are closer to the German meaning.

At first sight, it appears, that Greek, German and English restricted to different meanings. In Greek nowadays the - virtually sole -  sense is "passive".

Comment: Interesting indeed. But are pathetic and pathetisch not both adjectives of the word pathos, which comes from the greek πάθος ‎(páthos: “suffering, misfortune”) which in turn comes from πάσχω (páskho: "to suffer, to endure")? Also, the description of pathos seems very close to the meaning of pathetisch but not really close to the meaning of pathetic.

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann indeed, but as the adjective was already formed in ancient times, I started from there.

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann, Wiktionary lists as the meaning of πάσχω both "suffer" and "feel". There the modern English and the German meaning come nicely together.